# pecl_http 2.5.3 on php 5.5.33 Unable to load dynamic library http.so undefined symbol: php_resource_factory_handle_ctor

Tags: php, http, request, pecl

I am trying to use pecl_http 2.5.3 on my CentOS server, I have already installed it but when I do.

```
$request = new http\Client\Request("GET",
$endpoint,
[ "Api-Key"     => $apiKey,
  "X-Signature" => $signature,
  "Accept"      => "application/xml" ]);
```

I get the following error: **Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/plesk/php/5.5/lib64/php/modules/http.so' - /opt/plesk/php/5.5/lib64/php/modules/http.so: undefined symbol: php_resource_factory_handle_ctor in /var/www/vhosts/bojorquez.viajes/httpdocs/desarrollo/panel/model/beds.php on line 5**.

After installing it, I ran the following commands, to assign the location of the php.ini in which I have this:

```
pecl config-set php_ini /opt/plesk/php/5.5/etc/php.ini
pear config-set php_ini /opt/plesk/php/5.5/etc/php.ini
```

My php.ini is as follows:

```
   extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/raphf.so
   extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/propro.so
   extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so
```

In that order, I think that the "php_resource_factory_handle_ctor" comes from raph extension, but I have already included it and I don't know what's wrong, any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, since I have a server which has different domains along with different versions of PHP, the one that I installed compiled with the server php version, which is 5.4.16, so I changed my vhost domain to that version, and just included the same extension route. That worked for me, I don't know though if I could install pecl on a certain version that had the server.